# enableCellChangeflash is not working on update with ag-grid

Tags: ag-grid

I am exploring ag-grid and for the life of me cannot get any cells to flash on an update. The example code works in the documentation but it's triggered via a button click. If I'm fetching data periodically and updating the grid with `gridOptions.api.setRowData(data);`  then how am I supposed to trigger the flashing?

The update process works fine... the grid data changes accordingly but there is no flashing of the updated cells.

```
  const gridOptions = {

    columnDefs: [
      ...
    ],

    // default col def properties get applied to all columns
    defaultColDef: {
      sortable: true,
      filter: false,
      suppressSizeToFit: false,
      enableCellChangeFlash: true,
    },


    animateRows: true, // have rows animate to new positions when sorted
    domLayout: 'autoHeight',

    onGridReady: getData(),
    onGridReady: (event) => event.api.sizeColumnsToFit(),

  };
```

Any guidance/help is appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

After trying a few more approaches, once I set the row ID with a value from the data, the flashes started working...

```
       const gridOptions = {
         ...
         getRowId: params => params.data.id,
         ...
       }
```

More details here [Application Assigned IDs](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/row-ids/#application-assigned-ids)